# Composer fails within Docker 'Failed to enable crypto'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, proxy, laradock

I've been battling an issue with a corporate proxy when trying to run `docker-compose up -d nginx mysql`

I'm attempting to run the Laradock container on OSX but keep running into errors when composer attempts to install dependencies. I've updated my docker settings to notify it about my corporate proxy:

[image: docker proxy settings]

Before adding the proxy information, I was receiving this error:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
  error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

Since updating the proxy details, I am now receiving this error:

```
Step 27/183 : RUN if [ ${COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL} = true ]; then     composer global install ;fi
 ---> Running in a7699d4ecebd
Changed current directory to /home/laradock/.composer
Loading composer repositories with package information

  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL: Success
  Failed to enable crypto
  failed to open stream: operation failed
```

I'm an experienced dev, but new to Docker. I think that the error is being caused because PHP is running inside the docker container but for some reason does not have access to my local certificates?